# PlayFramework 2.5: HikariCP ignores some (but not all) settings from application.conf

Tags: playframework, hikaricp

I am a little bit confused about the configuration of HikariCP in PlayFramework 2.5.

I added that to my `application.conf` file:

```
play.db {
  # The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  config = "db"
  default = "default"  
  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 30
    hikaricp.connectionTimeout = 5 seconds
    hikaticp.maxLifetime = 10 seconds
    hikaticp.idleTimeout = 5 seconds
  }
}

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=${?JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
db.default.username=${?DATABASE_USERNAME}
db.default.password=${?DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

That works fine. I get a connection to the Database and can submit queries and all. My Problem is, that only a part of the HikariCP settings are used. At the start of the application I catch the used HikariCP parameters:

```
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,413 ] [info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,424 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - configuration:
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,430 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - catalog.........................null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............5000
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - dataSource......................null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,431 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................600000
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - initializationFailFast..........true
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl........................."XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - maxLifetime.....................1800000
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize.................30
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - metricRegistry..................null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory...........null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - minimumIdle.....................30
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - password........................<masked>
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - readOnly........................false
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - registerMbeans..................false
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutorService........null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - threadFactory...................null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation............null
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - username........................"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
[ 2017-02-23 11:12:58,432 ] [debug] c.z.h.HikariConfig - validationTimeout...............5000
```

The values for `maximumPoolSize` and `connectionTimeout` are as set in the `application.conf`. But the values for `maxLifetime` and `idleTimeout` are ignored and set to other values.

Is the syntax of the `application.conf` wrong in some points and I do not see the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very small, try to set something like 5 minutes.

Right now you must to see in the log messages similar to

```
maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, using default 1800000ms.
```

The code from the source of [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.4.x/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java):

```
LOGGER.warn("{} - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default {}ms.", poolName, MAX_LIFETIME);
...
LOGGER.warn("{} - idleTimeout is less than 10000ms, setting to default {}ms.", poolName, IDLE_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: Thanks! Something like minimal values for that variables was also in my mind, but i have not found hints for that. Besides: The real problem of the application was bad connection handling which has led to a connection pool without free connections after a short time. With that problem solved we did not need so short maxLifetime values.